# How hook work in drupal?

Tags: hooks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is basic concept behind hooks?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/26290/what-is-basic-concept-behind-hooks)

How does comment_field_extra_fields() implement hook_field_extra_fields()? How is a hook implemented by another function?  Does it extend another class to use a hook function?

Comment: See [`module_implements()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!module.inc/function/module_implements/7) and [`module_invoke()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!module.inc/function/module_invoke/7) in the API, and [this excellent resouce](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/26290/what-is-basic-concept-behind-hooks/26322#26322)

Comment: This is also a good read: http://alanstorm.com/drupal_module_hooks

Comment: I found this to be very useful in understanding Drupal's hook system: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/26290/what-is-basic-concept-behind-hooks