# How to have a drupal module respond on node creation

Tags: nodes

I am trying to convert some of my rules to a custom module for more flexibility and better configuration.

However, I am stuck; I want my module to read some fields on node creation (or update). In rules there is the event property where I can choose 'on creation of node'.

I suppose I have to use a hook of some sort, but hooks like `hook_node_insert()` (and some others) that respond on a node being created (or saved) are depending on a node parameter; `hook_node_insert($node)`.

So how do I get this node property?

Comment: I think you're slightly misunderstanding hooks, have a look at http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/26290/what-is-basic-concept-behind-hooks it should clear things up.

Comment: In the example they say `hook_node_delete` can be used to do thing if a certain node gets deleted. Basically I want to do the same on node creation. So I do assume hooks is the way to go. But all hooks that deal with node creation, insertion, etc. are depending on a $node parameter. Is this an object? a nid? or something I can define myself (eg. specifying types, revisions, dates, etc.)

Comment: You _implement_ a hook and some other part of the system will call it. The `$node` object is passed to your implementation by the invoking function, it's not something you set up yourself

Comment: Oke, that is clear now. But then how do I make my module respond on such calls? Like hook on to it?

Comment: You need to [write a custom module](http://drupal.org/developing/modules), simply write `function MYMODULE_node_insert($node) { // function code }`. Once Drupal's caches have been cleared the code you've written inside that function will be called whenever a node is inserted

Comment: I feel so stupid right now. I assumed `$details=node_insert($node)` requiring me to enter a value for $node. I never thought drupal would place a call to my module. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All credits to [Clive](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/2800/clive), but here is the answer.

You need to write a custom module: Simply write a `MYMODULE_node_insert($node)` function containing the code you want to execute. Drupal will call that function every time a node is created (when the module is enabled).

If you are changing the code of a module that is already enabled, you should clear Drupal caches, as otherwise Drupal will not notice the module contains a new hook implementation. This can be achieved by disabling the module before editing it, and re-enabling it after the code has been changed.