# user register hook form alter not reaching

Tags: users, forms

I am trying to request more information from users when they register for my site.  I put a set-message in and it's not eve appearing nor any changes in the user register form.

I cant seem to find anything online to work, any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

```
 <?php
       function hook_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){

         drupal_set_messge($form_id);

         if ($form_id == "user_register_form") {
              $form['account']['name']['#title'] = t('Full name');

              $form['city'] = array(
                '#type' => 'textfield', 
                '#title' => t('City'),
                '#size' => 15,
                '#required' => TRUE,
              );

              $form['state'] = array(
                '#type' => 'textfield', 
                '#title' => t('State'),
                '#size' => 15,
                '#required' => TRUE,
               );

               $form['#submit'][] = 'hook_from_alter_submit';

          }

     }

    function hook_form_alter_submit($form, &$form_state) {

       $city = $form_state['values']['city'];
       $state = $form_state['values']['state'];
    }

 ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The naming convention for hooks is:

```
MODULENAME_hook_name()
```

So to implement `hook_form_alter()` in a module called `MYMODULE`, your function would be defined as:

```
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  // ...
}
```

Have a look at [What is the basic concept behind hooks?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/26290/what-is-basic-concept-behind-hooks) for a more detailed explanation.

Comment: See the WSOD help guide: http://drupal.org/node/158043

Comment: I changed that and I fixed the typo in the drupal_set_message and still nothing is showing up. File names are user_reg.info and user_reg.module and the functions are user_reg_form_alter and user_reg_form_alter_submit

Comment: Well the other person working on the site installed some random mail modules, and now the login works... Thanks!