# why doesn't system_menu() return the option I am expecting

Tags: 7, hooks, configuration

If you go to this website: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.module/function/system_menu/7

You will see what system_menu is supposed to output. My Drupal 7 has a jquery update under the development menu in the configuration tab. Why doesn't the jquery update option show up? Is there another function that I should be looking at?

Thanks!

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. system_menu() is not supposed to print anything in the screen. It throws whatever the system module needs to include in the menu system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to know what you mean, but at a guess you're expecting `system_menu()` to be responsible for *all* of the paths you can visit in the system, and therefore you're expecting to see a listing of all paths in that function?

If so, that's not quite how it works. Drupal is extended by way of a [hook system](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/26290/what-is-the-basic-concept-behind-hooks), one of those being [`hook_menu()`](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/62473), which allows modules to define menu items and page callbacks.

So in the case of jQuery Update, this is [its implementation of `hook_menu()`](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!jquery_update!jquery_update.module/function/jquery_update_menu/7):

```
function jquery_update_menu() {
  $items['admin/config/development/jquery_update'] = array(
    'title' => 'jQuery update', 
    'description' => 'Configure settings related to the jQuery upgrade, the library path and compression.', 
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form', 
    'page arguments' => array('jquery_update_settings_form'), 
    'access arguments' => array('administer site configuration'),
  );

  return $items;
}
```

And that's where the jQuery Update admin menu item and link come from.