# Display all nodes for which user appears as a field on that user's profile?

Tags: 7, users

I have a site with a content type "Projects," which has a field "Project Manager" that takes a user. Is there a good way to display all Projects for which a user appears as the Project Manager for that Project on that user's profile?

Update:

Here is what I have so far in user_profile.tpl.php

```
...
function my_module_user_view($account, $view_mode, $langcode) {

  $my_field = 'field_pm';
  $uid = $account->uid; // The uid of the user being viewed.
  $query = "SELECT entity_id FROM {field_data_{$my_field}} WHERE {$my_field}_target_id = :uid AND bundle='user'";
  $args = array(':uid' => $uid,);
  $result = db_query($query, $args);
  $nids = $result->fetchCol();
  if (count($nids)) {
    $projects = node_load_multiple($nids); // Load all projects where that user is a PM
    foreach ($projects as $project) {
      $account->content['field_pm_projects'][0]['#markup'] = $project->title;
    }
  }
}
?>

<div class="profile"<?php print $attributes; ?>>
 <?php print render($user_profile); ?>
 <?php print $account->content['field_pm_projects']; ?></span>
</div>
```

Comment: `has a field "Project Manager" that takes a user` is this an entity reference field?

Comment: @NoSssweat: yup, it is..

Comment: so you want to display all the projects the user is a project manager on their user profile page, right?

Comment: exactly @NoSsseat

Comment: Check the function's signature [views_embed_view](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.module/function/views_embed_view/7), the first argument must be a view not a field. Keep in mind that it is not a good practice to implement hooks in  .tpl files.

Answer (score 1):

Add a contextual filter for that entity reference field and in its settings, provide default: uid from url. That will only show nodes where the uids match.

There are two options, "referenced" and "referencing".. I'm pretty sure you want referenced but try both.

Comment: Hm, I'm not editing a view though. I actually want to add an element to the user profile..Thank you for your response!

Comment: If you place the view as block on user pages, it will work at a basic level.  I think you should add some more information to your opening post.. Solutions given so far answer the initial question.

Comment: @JillianHoenig you could use a **[view block](http://i.stack.imgur.com/SMaZK.jpg)** not view page.

Comment: I know. It's a complicated relationship though (I messed with a couple of configurations, with no success). Right now I am toying with db_select, by I'm pretty new to php :/

Comment: Did you try the view i described above as a block? What functionality do you need with this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using entity reference for the Project Manager field, you could use [(Entity)Reference Field Synchronization](https://www.drupal.org/project/ref_field) module and create another companion field ("Managed Projects") on the User profile. The module keeps them in sync so that if you add a username to the Project Manager field, the Managed Project field will populate automatically. The same would go in reverse. Views would be another option.

Comment: That sounds like a great module. There must be a way to do in programmatically, though..

Answer (score 0):

You have to utilize that reference field of yours. I'll try to give you a rough idea:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_user_view().
 */ 
function my_module_user_view($account, $view_mode, $langcode) {

  $my_field = 'field_my_field';
  $uid = $account->uid; // The uid of the user being viewed.
  $query = "SELECT entity_id FROM {field_data_{$my_field}} WHERE {$my_field}_target_id = :uid AND bundle='user'";
  $args = array(':uid' => $uid,);
  $result = db_query($query, $args);
  $nids = $result->fetchCol();
  if (count($nids)) {
    $projects = node_load_multiple($nids); // Load all projects where that user is a PM
    foreach ($projects as $project) {
      $account->content['field_pm_projects'][0]['#markup'] = $project->title; 
    }
  }
}
```

You will need a second field (`field_pm_projects`) to store that info or you may print them on the theme direct, it depends on what you want to do. The chosen hook/preprocess also depends on the implementation you want to follow.

Comment: wow, thank you for your detailed response. Is it possible to implement some variation of this code on user_profile file, and somehow draw the uid from url??

Again, thanks so so much. This issue has been driving me crazy o_O

Comment: Yes, you can implement that code wherever you like. I guess that that `user_profile` file is a template. I have updated my answer so to fit to what you said about the `uid` from url. All I did was to implement a different hook ([hook_user_view](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.api.php/function/hook_user_view/7)) that always gives you the user entity being viewed. So no need for extracting the uid from the url.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks! I'm kinda new to this though... (and for future reference) would you mind explaining what all the variables are, to help me figure out what I need to substitute for them (eg $account, $view_mode, etc)...?

Comment: You don't have to substitute any variables, use them as they are. These variables are provided by the  drupal's  [hook system](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/26290/what-is-the-basic-concept-behind-hooks) ([more](https://www.drupal.org/node/292)). You may alter their names, though. The only variable you have to change is the `$my_field` with your field's name and you only know that name.

Comment: Would you mind taking a look at the code I've updated my question with and see if you can tell what's wrong. Thank you this has gotten me so much further along I think I'm nearly there..